# How to go about searching a server for a specific file?

Tags: c#, file, search, url, httpwebrequest

I am attempting to find a specific file on a web(site/server), and this file could have varying extensions depending upon the server. How would I determine the extension for a unique sever?

Example Possibilities:

website.com/list.**bz2**

--or--

website.com/list.**gz**

Comment: Really not sure what you're asking.

Comment: It would be somewhat like searching a directory on your harddisk for a file, without knowing the particular extension of the file, only the name.

Comment: So you're looking to search the Internet, looking for a particular entity, such that `http://foo.com/bar/baz.abc.xyz` is equivalent to `ftp://quux.com/baz.abc.txt` (to present a difficult case)? Why is this question tagged C# and httpwebrequest? It seems like 99% of the work here is how to query Google/Baidu/etc.

Comment: Because, what I would like to do, in essence, is search a directory of a website with a csharp application, to determine a certain file's existence. Somewhat like using System.IO.DirectoryInfo() on a url instead of a local filesystem.

Comment: Does your application run on the server machine itself, or from a client machine? If it's the former, then you can do this - enumerate all the files in the app directory. If it's the latter, sorry, no, (most) websites don't work like that.

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class App
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string searchPath = @"c:\";
        string searchPattern = "list.*";

        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(searchPath);
        FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            Console.WriteLine(file.FullName);

        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

If you don't have access to server and want to search it as a anonymous client, then you should search internet for `google hacking`.

Comment: URI formats aren't supported in the 'GetFiles' method of DirectoryInfo.

Comment: As I said, it doesn't work remotely. You need a crawler (web spider). The hard part of coding a crawler is finding files since most of servers don't allow directory browsing. In real world crawlers follow links in pages and find other pages. So for a non-linked page, you just can guess the file name.